# What are the open sets in $E$?

Tags: general-topology

I'm stuck finding what are the open sets in $E=\{(x,y) :(x-1)^2 +y^2 =1\} \cup \{(x,y) :(x+1)^2 +y^2 =1\}$. Considering the usual topology (induced on the circles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when we induce the Euclidean topology on this substance, then we simply define the open sets on the circles joined at the origin as the intersection of some open set in $R^2$ with the circles.

That is, we can form a “random” open set in the sub space defined above by taking some open set in the plane and simply intersecting it with the circles. What does this intersection look like? It looks like fuzzy segments on the circles. The basis of topology is simply any curve on the two circles excluding the endpoints of that curve. Of course if we consider the open ball at the origin, you’ll notice that a curve in the shape of a cross appears.

This subspace serves as a manifold that can “mostly” be described by $R$. So in some ways you can intuit from an information density point of view that the open sets are going to be similar to that of $R$, which are fuzzy segments on the number line.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the open subsets of $E$ in the 2-d Euclidean topology?  $E$ is the union of two circles.  A circle has no interior points, hence no open subsets.

Or, are we talking about the topology *induced* on the circles by the Euclidean 2-d topology?

Comment: The second one.

Comment: I don't know how to define them explicitly.

Comment: The induced open subsets of $E$ are the intersections of 2-d Euclidean open sets with $E$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**  $E$ is the union of the circle of radius $1$ and center $(1,0)$, and the union of the circle of radius $1$ and center $(-1,0)$.